# Ubuntu snappy core launcher failed: error loading shared libraries librt.so.1 file: no such file or directory

Tags: launcher, ubuntu-core, snap

I'm running Ubuntu Snappy Core on a Dell IoT Edge gateway.
    I have installed the following Debian packages:

```
libnm-glib
pptp-linux
pppor
usb-modeswitc
libcurl3
```

I restarted the system. Now the Ubuntu Core launcher is not loading any snap packages installed by Canonical support team like network manager, `bluez`, `ccm-wda` etc.

What should I do?